# Не работает style.css на Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

В общем искал по теме, но не нашел. Не подгружаются изменения в файле темы `style.css`, плагины кэширования отсутствуют, да и вообще в принципе весь кэш отключен. Есть какое-то решение?

Comment: Вроде на сколько помню там кешируются файлы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно в темах в файле header.php в head пишется так
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri() ?>" />`

Проверьте, есть ли у вас такое.